# Knockout draggable and sortable to different drop target

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, knockout.js

EDIT/tl;dr: Check out this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VZKRM/2/

I have a collection of tabs and within a tab is a collection of applications. I'm trying to get it so I can drag and sort applications within a tab, and drag an application out of a tab into another tab by dropping onto another tab's header.

I've been able to get sort working with the knockout sortable library (https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-sortable) but I can't seem to hook the drop into the other tab.

I think I'm hooking the drop incorrectly. Here's the html:

```
<div id="apps-tabs">
    <div id="apps-left">
        <div id="wrapper" class="wrapper NavPanel">
            <div class="NavData" id="v-nav">
                <ul id="tab-list" data-bind="foreach: Tabs">
                    <li class="TopNav drop-target">
                        <a data-bind="attr:{ tab: hash, 'tab-id': id }, text: name"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div>
                    <a data-bind="click: addTab">Add new...</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="apps-right">
        <div id="tab-container" data-bind="foreach: Tabs">
            <div class="tab-content" data-bind="attr:{id:hash, 'tab-id':id}">
                <h1 data-bind="text: name"></h1>
                <ul class="my-apps" data-bind="sortable: {data: applications, connectClass: 'drop-target', options: { placeholder: 'app-drop-placeholder', delay: 50, tolerance: 'pointer' } }">
                    <li data-bind="attr:{'app-id':id}" class="app app-inner">
                        <div class="app-inner-anchor">&nbsp;</div>
                        <div style="height: 95px;">
                            <a data-bind="attr:{title:name, href:url, target:target}">
                                <img class="app-image" style="padding-top: 20px" data-bind="attr:{alt:name, src:imagePath}" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div style="height: 30px;">
                            <a data-bind="attr:{title:name, href:url, target:target}, text: name"></a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's my view model:

```
function TabViewModel(tabs) {
    var self = this;

    self.Tabs = ko.observableArray(tabs);
}

function Tab(name, id, hash, apps) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.hash = hash;

    this.applications = ko.observableArray(apps || []);
}

function Application(name, id, url, imagePath, target) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.url = url;
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
    this.target = target;
}

ko.applyBindings(new TabViewModel([
    new Tab('tab 1', 1, 'tab1', [
        new Application('app 1', 1, 'http://foo/foo/', 'http://foo/img.png', '_blank'), 
        new Application('app 2', 2, 'http://foo/foo/', 'http://foo/img.png', '_blank'), 
        new Application('app 3', 3, 'http://foo/foo/', 'http://foo/img.png', '_blank')]),
    new Tab('tab 2', 2, 'tab2', [
        new Application('app 4', 4, 'http://foo/foo/', 'http://foo/img.png', '_blank'),
        new Application('app 5', 5, 'http://foo/foo/', 'http://foo/img.png', '_blank'),
        new Application('app 6', 6, 'http://foo/foo/', 'http://foo/img.png', '_blank')]),
        ]));
```

If it's not clear there is a ul of tab headers, and each li in it has a class of 'drop-target'. Each tab has an associated div with a class of 'tab-container' and it has a ul with a class of 'my-apps' for applications. Each application can sort within it's own ul, but also be droppable onto the tab header's .drop-target. Once dropped on the .drop-target it get's added into the associated .my-apps ul.

How do I wire up the .drop-target to accept the application li? In the fiddle posted I have the two functions BindSort/BindDrop that I would like to knockout.

Comment: Maybe you can strip down this fiddle and get it working close to what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/tC7TL/

Comment: That was a good idea :) I've updated the post to include a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VZKRM/2/